# Compare conflicting values in two arrays - Visual Basic

Tags: arrays, vba, compare

In Visual Basic I have an array that goes from 1 to 100. I then have an input box that you can put numbers into (for example: 1 5 6 9 10 20 etc) the application splits the numbers between spaces and puts them as items in a new array. How can I get the VALUES in 1 to 100 array and the VALUES in the input array and compare them, and if they conflict (say if the input one has the same as the 1 to 100 one) then do something?

the code for the 1 to 100 array:

```
Dim baseArray(0 To 100) As Integer  
For a = 0 To UBound(baseArray)
    no += 1
    baseArray(a) = 0 + no
Next a
```

the code for the splitting input array:

```
Dim givenNoArray() As String  
givenNo = input_numbers.Text
givenNoArray = givenNo.Split(" ")

For i = 0 To UBound(givenNoArray)
    Debug.Print(givenNoArray(i))
Next i
```

So that all works. Just comparing them is my problem.

Comment: To compare the elements at the same index value, you just need one loop and look at baseArray(index) versus givenNoArray(index) with an If statement. If you want to compare each element in givenNoArray with each element in baseArray, then you need two loops - one is called a nested loop since it exists inside the other loop. The outer loop loops through every element in givenNoArray and the inner loop will loop through every element in baseArray. And then you look at givenNoArray(outer_index) versus baseArray(inner_index) in an if statement

Comment: so a Do While loop would work?

Comment: It looks like you will have all valid data in both arrays, so For Loop through every entry seems best.

Comment: okay ill try that. But how exactly do I get the value of the position in the array and not the array position number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For i = 0 To UBound(givenNoArray)
    For j = 0 To UBound(baseArray)
        If givenNoArray(i) = baseArray(j) Then
            Console.WriteLine("match of givenNoArray element " &
                              i & " and baseArray element  " & j)
            Console.WriteLine("value of match is " & givenNoArray(i))
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: that does work but when I try to put it onto a text (each one array item) it only lists the ones it conflicts with so if 2 numbers were to conflict instead of listing 1 to 100 and saying that 2 conflicts it lists 2 numbers. How can I fix that?

Comment: I don't understand what "put it onto a text" means.

Comment: Instead of putting it in a console debug like you have done. I have put it onto label text. Each time it cycles through it draws a label on the screen each under eachother. Ive made it so that the ones that conflict are a different colour. Look here:
http://pastie.org/private/hr9opuqqxsrqehvtlrmga 

but it doesnt draw them all properly.

Comment: @fire_head Unfortunately I do not know Visual Basic. I would ask another question, this time making it with regard to how to get the output to go to a text label as you desire.